# Get user group id then print list of users with same group id

Tags: c

Hi there i am trying to list all the user names that have a group id that matches your user id. I was thinking to use getpwent but cant seem to get it right seem to get a infinite loop and i am not sure home to filter out only the ones with the same group name.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
 uid_t myId;
 myId = getuid();

 struct passwd *pPwdInfo = NULL;
 pPwdInfo  = getpwuid(myId);

 if((pPwdInfo = getpwuid(myId)) != NULL){
   int gId = pPwdInfo->pw_gid;

   struct passwd *pwd_entry = NULL;
   pwd_entry  = getpwent();

   setpwent(); // go to the top of /etc/passwd

   while(pwd_entry){
    printf("Username: %s\n", pwd_entry->pw_name);
    printf("Password: %s\n", pwd_entry->pw_passwd);
    printf("User Id: %d\n", pwd_entry->pw_uid);
    printf("Group Id: %d\n", pwd_entry->pw_gid);
    printf("User info: %s\n", pwd_entry->pw_gecos);
    printf("Home Directory: %s\n", pwd_entry->pw_dir);
    printf("Shell Program: %s\n", pwd_entry->pw_shell);
   }

   endpwent();
 }else{

 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: what use would that have? There is no necessary correlation between UID ang GID, even if you have user-groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the man page

> The `getpwent()` function returns a pointer to a structure containing
>   the broken-out fields of a record from the password database (e.g.,
>   the local password file /etc/passwd, NIS, and LDAP).  The first time
>   `getpwent()` is called, it returns the first entry; thereafter, it
>   returns successive entries.

So you forgot to successively call `getpwent()` inside the loop.

```
while(pwd_entry){
    if (pwd_entry->pw_gid == uid_you_want_to_match) {
        printf("Username: %s\n", pwd_entry->pw_name);
        printf("Password: %s\n", pwd_entry->pw_passwd);
        printf("User Id: %d\n", pwd_entry->pw_uid);
        printf("Group Id: %d\n", pwd_entry->pw_gid);
        printf("User info: %s\n", pwd_entry->pw_gecos);
        printf("Home Directory: %s\n", pwd_entry->pw_dir);
        printf("Shell Program: %s\n", pwd_entry->pw_shell);
    }
    pwd_entry = getpwent()
}
```